# rails don't find the attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

I have this model

```
#post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    after_initialize :create_token
    attr_accessible :token
    protected
    def create_token
      self.token = "#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{self.id}")[0,4]}"
    end 
end
```

in `rails c`

```
Post.find(:all,:conditions => { :user_id => 11})
 => [#<Post id: 26, content: "<p><strong>Yao Ming</strong> (<a shape=\"rect\" title...", user_id: 11, created_at: "2011-07-12 15:08:30", updated_at: "2011-07-12 15:08:30", title: "Yao Ming", guid: "0010f6c3-040b-4e13-aa38-3a002e6f2022", contentHash: "\xB9\\\xCBK\xB0A>4\xC4~\xFC\"\xEA7\xA6y", token: "4e73">]
```

when the `token: "4e73"`, but when I try

```
Post.find(:all,:conditions => { :user_id => 11, :token => "4e73"}) 
 => []
```

I get `[]`, why ?

#### more information

```
Post.find(:all,:conditions => { :user_id => 11}).first.token.class
=> String 

Post.find(:all,:conditions => { :user_id => 11}).first.token
=> "3769"
```

Comment: What do you get for `Post.find(:all,:conditions => { :token => "4e73"}) `

Comment: Post.find(:all,:conditions => {  :token => "4e73"})  
 => []

Comment: And `Post.find(:all,:conditions => { :user_id => 11}).first.token.class`?

Comment: Post.find(:all,:conditions => { :user_id => 11}).first.token.class
 => String

Answer (score 2):

According to Rails Guides:

> The after_initialize callback will be called whenever an Active Record
>   object is instantiated, either by directly using new or when a record
>   is loaded from the database.

You should probably find another way to initialize this 'token' field, otherwise it will be changed every time you reload the record from database.

Answer (score 1):

As Eugen says, That is the problem, In all case Rails has no native way to does that, so what you have to do is:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    after_initialize :create_token
    attr_accessible :token
    protected
    def create_token
        if new?
          self.token = "#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{self.id}")[0,4]}"
        end
    end 
end
```

or simply

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    attr_accessible :token
    protected
    def after_initialize
        if new?
          self.token = "#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{self.id}")[0,4]}"
        end
    end 
end
```

Comment: Edit the after_initialize callback, you can use it like create_token function in your code

Answer (score 1):

Well, to build an attribute based on the `id`, the `id` must exist. Finally, do this:

```
after_create :create_token

def create_token
  self.token = "#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{self.id}")[0,4]}"
  self.save
end
```

Comment: Yep, the main issue is that in the original code the token is never saved to the database.

Comment: @Alex - Aotea Studios: I don't understand your comment

Comment: I was just agreeing with your answer. As far as I can see, the code in the question initialises the token but never saves it, which is why `find` doesn't work.

Comment: well, it was initialized before_save with different ways to do that so it was kind of implicit. But yep, there was no example

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
before_create :create_token
```

so it's only generated when the record is first inserted into the database.

Comment: with before_create any post.token is called equal

Comment: Right. I missed that you were creating your token based on self.id. Change your token builder to use the title plus the content plus the time to generate a unique md5 token rather than just the id. I see some have suggested using after_create but I don't like that only because you end up with an INSERT to create the record and then an UPDATE the set the token. With before_create, you just have the INSERT. Anything one can do to minimize database access is a good thing, IMHO.